# Binary search line of code

Tags: c, binary-search

I've been trying to learn how the binary search works, so I searched for a code and tried to understand what each line does. There is this one line that I don't understand. The line with the "return -1". I don't understand what that means. Can someone explain what happens in that line of code?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int array[], int size, int searchValue){
int low = 0;
int high = size - 1;

while(low<=high){// is the array exhausted?
    int mid = (low + high) / 2; //If not, find the middle index

    if(searchValue == array[mid]){
        return mid;
    }
    else if(searchValue > array[mid]){
        low = mid + 1;
    }
    else{
        high = mid - 1;
    }
}
return -1;
}

int main(){
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int searchNum;

printf("Enter an integer:");
scanf("%d", &searchNum);

int result = binarySearch(array,7,searchNum);

if(result>=0){
    printf("Found!");
}
else{
    printf("Not found!");
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: −1 indicates that the value was not found.

Comment: it means if no search found then return -1 else it will return the postion of the found element

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary Search is performed in array and array's position start from 0. So if -1 is return means that position is not in the array or can not be located.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is performed and contains a return statement, if the item you are looking for is in the array, then the return in the `while` loop will return the index of the item. The `return -1` statement that follows returns to the caller if the item is not found, ie if `high>low`, -1 is used to indicate that it is in the array as an index of -1 is outside the bounds of any array. Without the `return -1` statement then there would be a compile time error saying that the return statement is missing

When you perform your check

```
if(result>=0) {
printf("Found!");
} else {
printf("Not found!");
}
```

If the binary search method finds the item and returns the index(which will be >-1) then *"Found!* will be printed to the console, else if the binary search method returns a value <0, ie -1 then the item has not been found in the array, and thus *Not Found!* is printed to the console, your if statement alone can give your binary search a good explantation!